# Writing database by id

Tags: anylogic

I want to fill a database using the insert into method according to the Id of an operation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bDwp.png

So, at the beginning of a block I defined the function so that it would insert the data into the database:

insertInto(transferencias_orsub).columns(transferencias_orsub.id,
transferencias_orsub.data_inicio, transferencias_orsub.produto,
transferencias_orsub.volume).values(id,date(),agent.produtoP,agent.demandaPp).execute();

I would like, in the "On exit" block, to insert the date of the operation (date()) in the same row as the id.

Could you give me any suggestions on how I can do this check?

I tried using the following function to update the database

`update(transferencias_orsub).where(transferencias_orsub.id.eq(id)).set(transferencias_orsub.data_fim, date()).execute();`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it like that. Collect all your data first and then write it in one action.

To collect it neatly, best create Java class instances that hold the data. You can write/update your date field in there and write the entire thing when it is done.

You may even want to write all data out in one go at the model end only, else you complicate things in the long run